# How to freeze header row or header text row in rally tree grid

Tags: rally, code-rally

How we can freeze the first row or header text row in rally tree grid.

can you please share the code ?

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at the [enableLocking](https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/api/Ext.panel.Table-cfg-enableLocking) config property on the TreeGrid...

None of the grids in Rally use this so I'm not sure if it will work or not.  But perhaps worth a try...

Comment: I tried this but getting an Exception like "sdk-debug.js:194423 Uncaught TypeError: this.getTreeStore(...).getRootNode is not a function"